# Mysql - Can I have a child that doesn't get deleted when the parent is deleted?

Tags: mysql

I've got a table 1 that references a table 2 as a foreign key, but would like to keep the other data I've stored in table 1 even if the row referenced by table 1 in table 2 is deleted. Is that allowed?

Comment: One you could easily test yourself.

Comment: One approach to this is soft deletion, whereby you don't actually delete records, you just mark them as deleted.  Then, key relationships never have to be broken.

Comment: Sure. Find out more about referential actions in MySQL (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html#foreign-keys-referential-actions) and ON DELETE and ON UPDATE subclauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you check the documentation on foreign keys, you will come across "ON DELETE". Every foreign key has a mode set for how it should react when the parent gets deleted. "ON DELETE CASCADE" means the child will be deleted as well, "... RESTRICT" means you can't delete the parent of a child exists and "... SET NULL" means the child loses the reference to the parent instead of getting deleted as well.

Comment: in short
CASCADE - deletes related record
RESTRICT - prevents deletion
 SET NULL - is what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can just delete the reference id
Say

Table1 : id , name 
Table2 : id1, id(foreign key of table1)

alter table table2 drop foreign key id;
alter table table2 add foreign key(id) references table1(id) on delete set NULL;